# how to hide devise's notice tag in js/jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i am having trouble trying to hide the notice that devise provides after you successfully login using jquery. i want to hide it after a second of displaying however it is not working. here is what i have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p.notice").delay(1000).hide("slow");
});
```

I know the java script is getting excecuted because i put an alert in there to test it out. any idea why it isnt hiding the devise "notice" paragraph class:

```
<p class"notice">Signed in successfully.</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.delay` works with animations only try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $("p.notice").hide("slow");
   },1000);
});
```

Comment: are you sure the required element is in the DOM when you start manipulation is the class name same, it should worlk if there is `p` element in your DOM with a class = `notice`

Comment: im pretty sure. im looking at the html that is generated.

Comment: im thinking it has to do something with live or delegates. because the data isnt initially there.

Comment: if you are dynamically appending the data to the DOM then you have to manipulate it in the callback function, from the markup you provided in the question it doesn't give a clue about appending data dynamically, you should include the that is responsible for dynamic insertion of data ...